# Will my landlord fix a leaky faucet?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, residential-lease

I just got a lease to sign, but I am confused by some of the language.

My question in short is: what does "**public mains up to the point of entry**" mean?

**More information:**

It reads:

...

Landlord shall make all repairs which, in Landlord's discretion, are necessary to maintain
the following, subject to normal wear and tear:

**A.** The exterior and structural walls, excluding glass, structural floors, excluding
floor coverings, the foundations, roofs, gutters, and exterior downspouts of the
Leased Premises;

**B.** All appurtenances to the Leased Premises, including stairways, sidewalks,
driveways, tenant shall be responsible for normal maintenance. Tenant responsible
for grass cutting, lawn and yard maintenance. Tenant is responsible for snow
removal as may be required from time to time;

**C.** Water, sewage and gas and electrical lines from the public mains up to the
point of entry to the Leased Premises;

...

Does this mean that they or I will be responsible for plumbing repairs?
I am not sure what the term "**public mains up to the point of entry**" means.

Comment: Before you sign the lease ask the landlord to be use explicit terms *in the contract*, since the contract would also need to be intelligible to a court if a dispute arises. Without knowing the meaning of "mains" (which is why I post a comment instead of an answer), your conjecture makes sense: the clause altogether *apparently* means that tenant(s) would be responsible for plumbing/power/gas repairs, which seems odd.

Comment: *Will* he or *does he need to*?

Answer (score 4):

### You are responsible

The “public mains” are the infrastructure owned by the utility (and are the utility’s maintenance problem). From those, to the point where it enters the building (or your unit for a multi-unit building), they are the landlord’s problem. Within your leasehold they are your problem.

Notwithstanding, a leaky tap is probably a worn washer which is caught by the “fair wear and tear” clause anyway.